# Everything looks grainy and low res

Tags: resolution, appearance, display-resolution

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 on my  HP Touchsmart Pavilion laptop.

Everything looks lower res than it did in Windows, not just the fonts, but the video playback in VLC and eveything in my web browser. It looks pretty terrible.

I've searched this a bunch but I can't seem to find anyone else having this problem where EVERYTHING looks bad.

EDIT: This was solved by using the proprietary drivers and then restarting.

Comment: Tried different display refresh rates? Should be in same Display settings that has the different resolutions. Some monitors look fuzzy with some refresh rates.